# Mileage Deduction as Independent Contractor?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction

I will be starting a new independent contract in a few weeks.  The contract requires that I work at the client's office.

Can I deduct mileage for the drive to and from the office?

I may require purchasing/leasing a second car because of this particular engagement (my wife and I only have one car).  Would the answer change based on this?

Edit Note: just wanted to add that I have googled this extensively, and find conflicting answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drive from your home to work site you can not deduct the mileage because it is considered a commuting expense. Now if you have an office (not a home office) and drive to the office and then on to the client site it would be deductible.

Whether you buy or lease a car for the purpose won't have any affect on the deduct-ability (assuming sole prop or single per LLC).

Comment: Or if you have another job, then if you work at site A on one job, and then go the site B to work at the other job, then the mileage from Site A to Site B is deductible, but the mileage from home to Site A, or from Site B back home after a long day, is not deductible.